# Checking the length of strings in node.js

Tags: node.js

My friend is trying to build a discord bot, but he needs the length of the string. For example, he wants a command that would say Apple is 5, Eat is 3, etc etc. How could he go about doing this?

Comment: use `.length`
eg: var word='apple'
var wordLength = word.length

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm being dense, isn't this as simple as using `.length` on the string holding the word?

No need for any custom function to do it - `.length` is built in as can be seen in the docs for [string.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).

The snippet below shows an example of this:

```js
let words = ['apple', 'eat', 'hello world', 'martin'];

for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  let word = words[i];
  let len = word.length;
  
  console.log(`${word} is ${len}`);
}
```

If you specifically wanted a function that generated this, the following snippet shows one:

```js
function getWordLength(word) {
  return `${word} is ${word.length}`;
}

console.log(getWordLength('Apple'));
console.log(getWordLength('eat'));
```

#### Edit regarding Unicode

As helpfully pointed out by @RickN, strings that contain Unicode characters will give an invalid length because each Unicode character will be reported as having a length of 2 instead of 1.

The easy workaround is to resolve this is shown in the snippet below:

```js
function getWordLength(word) {
  let len = [...word].length
  return `${word} is ${len}`;
}

console.log(getWordLength('Apple'));
console.log(getWordLength('eat'));
console.log(getWordLength(''));
```

This is described in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#unicode) as provided by @RickN (thank you).

Comment: Do note that certain characters (for example emoji) count for two when using `.length`: `''.length===2`. You can [work around that pretty easily](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#unicode).

Comment: @RickN Thank you for that - an excellent point that I overlooked.  I've amended the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

Use the length proprety on your string like this. Easy cake!

```js
let someString = 'Apple';

console.log(`${someString} has ${someString.length} characters`);
```

But when you try to count only the characters and not the white spaces, replace first all the white spaces.

```js
let someString = 'Apple has the best phone';

console.log(`this sentence: "${someString}" has ${someString.replaceAll(' ', '').length} characters`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
str.length
```

Tell me what you tried...

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.length` to get the length and concatenate it with `string is`